# Socket Exception couldn't reconnect to the network in python

Tags: python, sockets, reconnect

when the network goes offline, the sockets throws error instead of reconnecting. It is reconnecting but not trying to achieve the connection. throws error in second or third attempt. Do I need to increase the wait time or is there anything which can be added to make sure the reconnect takes place

```
import socket,time
client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)    
client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

ip = '192.168.xx.x'
port = 4196
address = (ip,port)

client.connect(address)
print("connecting")


while 1:
    try:
        client.send(b'\x01\x04xxxxxxx')
        print("sent")
        data = client.recv(1024)
        print(data)
        time.sleep(5)
    except socket.error:
        while 1:
            print("error")
            client.close()
            time.sleep(30)
            print("reconnecting")
            client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            while 1:
                client.connect(address)
                print("connected back")
                break        
            break
```

OutPut:

```
connecting
sent
01 04 xxxxxxxxx
error
reconnecting
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Data\pwr\TCP.py", line 15, in <module>
    client.send(b'\x01\x04\xxxxxxxxxxx')
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\eclipse-workspace\Data\pwr\TCP.py", line 28, in <module>
    client.connect(address)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the second and the third `while 1` loops?Also, `ConnectionResetError` is not the same as `socket.error` (which is an `OSError`). Your exception handler is not catching `ConnectionResetError` .

Comment: Second and third while loop runs till it reconnects. Don't the ConnectionResetError comes under socket.error?

Comment: I do the ConnectionReset manually and it calls the exception socket.error I guess that part works fine, look at the OutPut.

Comment: The second and third loops run at most once each. If the reconnection is successful, they terminate. If it is not, there must be an uncaught exception because your code does not have exception handlers in the loops.

Comment: that solved my problem, thanks @DYZ